# One to one relationship for entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

So I've got 3 classes. For instance:

```
class Project {
    int id
}

class User {
    int id
}

class UserProjectLink {
    int projectId
    int userId
}
```

I have this approach in order to avoid `NULL` values in my database.
Entity framework however sets the `projectId` on my `User` table, thus resulting in `NULL` values. (note that the classes above are not the actual classes).

How can I solve this issue? A user will only have 1 project and a project will only have 1 user. The project may not yet have a user in which case the absence of a row in the `UserProjectLink` table would tell me there is not yet a user there.

Any ideas may be useful.

Comment: If you are using entity-framework, try to generate your classes from the database, the framework will create the object oriented representation. Meaning something like: project.User; and user.Project;

Comment: @Areks I don't recommend that route. Instead you should take the time to understand your model as Tikkes is doing here.

Comment: Are you using the code first approach. If yes then you set the table configuartions in the OnModelCreating() method. And dont allow the null in the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a setup where a project is a *weak entity* in relation to a user. This means that in order for a project to exist it **must have** a user as its owner, and it can't be referenced by any other users (i.e. it has a single owner).

So, you don't need the `UserProjectLink` table.

```
class User {
    int id
}

class UserProject { // or just "Project"
    int projectId
    int userId
}
```

Comment: This is true but there are 2 types of projects which will result in an inevitable null value on 1 field every time. That is why I thought this approach would help.

Comment: Maybe your question is missing information then. Why not just add a `typeId` field to the `UserProject` class as well? You also said that *each user will have only one project* - but it sounds like really they could have two each?

Comment: Okay so I took your advice and removed the link table. A user can only have one project and that project is one of 2 types. So I will end up with `null` values, I guess it isn't all that bad having `null` values in the end. or is it?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the table data would look like that will lead to having `NULL` values? Please edit your original question so the format can be shown. Regarding `NULL` values - they're not inherently bad. If they fit the real-world model then it's probably appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {
    [Key, ForeginKey("Project")]
    int id
    public Virtual Project Project{get; set;}
}
class Project {
    int id
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}
```